# Python user adding and controlling dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, request

I'm currently working on a project, and I keep running into a road block.
Let's say I have request.

```
requests.post("url.com", headers=headers)
```

How would I make it so a person could control the headers?
For example, how could one person add another value into the headers dictionary without having to open up the file and changing it? I mean from the command line. You would be able to tell the program during it's execution "These are the headers I want."

Comment: you could put headers into a separate file (let's say json), and load them into the python file and send them with the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use optparse to parse argument from command line:

```
from optparse import OptionParser

parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-h", "--headers", dest="headers", help="Specify the headers using the syntax: <header_name>=<value>,<header_name>=<value>,...", type="str", default=None)

(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
headers = options.headers
```

At this point, `header` is a string of headers separated by a comma. To get each header individually:

```
headers = headers.split(',')
headers_dict = {}
for h in headers:
    key, value = h.split('=')
    headers_dict[key] = value
```

Then, you pass the header via command line as:

```
python3 program_name.py -h header_1=value_1,header_2=value_2
```

Comment: Thank you! Just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the headers in an external JSON file like:

```
{
    "header_1": "header value",
    "header_2": "header value 2"
}
```

Then just load it when you need to build your request, i.e.:

```
import json

with open("path/to/your/headers.json", "r") as f:
    headers = json.load(f)

requests.post("url.com", headers=headers)
```

**UPDATE**: If you want to control the headers through the command line, the most basic approach is to use the [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv) list to access the CLI arguments so, for example, if you invoke your script as: `python script_name.py header1=value_1 header2=value_2`, you can turn that into a dict as:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1:  # ensure that we at least have some arguments
    headers = dict(x.split("=") for x in sys.argv[1:])
    requests.post("url.com", headers=headers)
else:
    print("At least one header required.")  # or whatever you want in that case...
```

But if you're looking for more robust CLI handling, I'd recommend checking the built-in [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html) module.

Comment: Hi! Thank you. I am not looking for a file based solution, but more of a way to declare the headers you want in the command line during the program. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass headers from the command line you could do the following:

```
import sys
headers = dict([header.split('=', 1) for header in sys.argv[1:]])
request.post("url.com", headers)
```

and then just call it by passing headers name and values like: `python file.py <header1>=<value1> <header2>=<value2>`